# How to get candidate group from process before deployment?

Tags: java, activiti

I want to get candidate group or candidate user from process before our deploy. How can I access to process definition variables and tasks before deployment?

Can I access this variable? Is it possible?

Comment: You can parse the Bpm model and get static info about it, including candidate starting groups. For variables, you can use

Comment: For variables you can get info from form definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to get all candidates for a specific task (`taskId`).

```
List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
List<IdentityLink> links = taskService.getIdentityLinksForTask(taskId);
for (IdentityLink link : links) {
    if (IdentityLinkType.CANDIDATE.equals(link.getType())) {
        String userId = link.getUserId();
        if (userId != null) {
            users.add(userId);
        }
        String groupId = link.getGroupId();
        if (groupId != null) {
            groups.add(groupId);
        }
    }
}
```